# Deleted parameter files were not removed with anisble change

Tags: ansible, prometheus, src

I've deleted the parameter in overrides.yml file but still that file entry is there in the instance.

For an instance:
if i remove instance_name: xyz01 entry in the overrides.yml and ran the ansible playbook but still xyz01 entry will be there in the **metrics** server..why is this skipping?
cat overrides.yml

```
abc:
  - instance_name: xyz01
    description: "Test instance "
    color: ""
    icon: ""
    server_port: 123
    management_port: 123


  - instance_name: xyz02
    description: "Test instance "
    color: ""
    icon: ""
    server_port: 123
    management_port: 123
```

if you see here, in order to create **abc-xyz0*** files, abc element is used, which does not have xyz03
cat abc.yml

```
- hosts: group-metrics
  tasks:
    - name: "Provision abc Metrics"
      include_role:
        name: metrics
      vars:
        abc: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ abc | default([]) }}"
```

which uses this task

```
---

- name: "{{ abc.instance_name }} - Create abc Prometheus Exporter"
  template:
    src: metrics-exporter.yml.j2
    dest: "/etc/prometheus/abc-{{ abc.instance_name }}.yml"
    owner: prometheus
    group: prometheus
    mode: 0644
```

which uses this template
metrics-exporter.yml.j2

```
- targets:
{% for host in groups[abc] %}
  - {{ host }}:{{ abc.management_port | default(123) }}| abc-{{ abc.instance_name }}

{% endfor %}
```

abc group contains : 3 instances

Answer (score 1):

The *vars* declaration below is wrong. First, the *vars* is evaluated, not *with_items*. Therefore *item* is missing

```yaml
    - name: "Provision abc Metrics"
      include_role:
        name: metrics
      vars:
        abc: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ abc | default([]) }}"
```

You should have seen the error:

```yaml
  TASK [include_role : metrics] ***************************************
  fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => 
  msg: '{{ item }}: ''item'' is undefined'
```

If you intend to use the variable *abc* for the iteration use *loop_control*. For example, given the data and the role below (simplified for testing)

```yaml
    abc:
      - instance_name: xyz01
      - instance_name: xyz02
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/metrics/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    var: abc
```

The task below

```yaml
    - include_role:
        name: metrics
      loop: "{{ abc|default([]) }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: abc
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [include_role : metrics] ********************************************
[WARNING]: The loop variable 'abc' is already in use. You should set the `loop_var` value in
the `loop_control` option for the task to something else to avoid variable collisions and
unexpected behavior.

TASK [metrics : debug] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  abc:
    instance_name: xyz01

TASK [metrics : debug] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  abc:
    instance_name: xyz02
```

The iteration works but Ansible complains about *abc* being already used. Use another variable to fix it. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat roles/metrics/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    var: abc_item
```

```yaml
    - include_role:
        name: metrics
      loop: "{{ abc|default([]) }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: abc_item
```

works fine

```yaml
TASK [include_role : metrics] **********************************************

TASK [metrics : debug] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  abc_item:
    instance_name: xyz01

TASK [metrics : debug] *****************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  abc_item:
    instance_name: xyz02
```

---

The next problem is the selection of the group in the template

```yaml
{% for host in groups[abc] %}
...
```

The variable *abc* is a list, not a name of a group. If you intend to iterate the hosts from the group 'abc' declare it. For example

```sh
shell> cat hosts
[abc]
abc_1
abc_2
abc_3
```

Then use it in the template (simplified for testing)

```yaml
shell> cat roles/metrics/templates/metrics-exporter.yml.j2
- targets:
{% for host in groups.abc %}
  - {{ host }}:{{ abc_item.instance_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

The template task should work as expected

```yaml
shell> cat roles/metrics/tasks/main.yml
- template:
    src: metrics-exporter.yml.j2
    dest: "/tmp/abc-{{ abc_item.instance_name }}.yml"
```

gives

```sh
shell> cat /tmp/abc-xyz01.yml 
- targets:
  - abc_1:xyz01
  - abc_2:xyz01
  - abc_3:xyz01

shell> cat /tmp/abc-xyz02.yml 
- targets:
  - abc_1:xyz02
  - abc_2:xyz02
  - abc_3:xyz02
```

---

If you want to control the presence of the files add an attribute to the list, e.g.

```yaml
    abc:
      - instance_name: xyz01
        present: false
      - instance_name: xyz02
```

and use it in the tasks

```yaml
shell> cat roles/metrics/tasks/main.yml
- file:
    state: absent
    dest: "/tmp/abc-{{ abc_item.instance_name }}.yml"
  when: not abc_item.present|d(true)|bool
- template:
    src: metrics-exporter.yml.j2
    dest: "/tmp/abc-{{ abc_item.instance_name }}.yml"
  when: abc_item.present|d(true)|bool
```

Comment: BTW I'm not getting any syntax errors(Syntax is fine)

Comment: my question is if you remove **- instance_name: xyz01** and run the playbook still you will be having a /tmp/abc-xyz01.yml file while shouldn't be right?

Comment: I updated the answer. If you don't update the question and make it [mre] it will be closed. There is no point in keeping questions that are not easily reusable. And, there is no point to answer such questions, of course.